# Change UITableViewCell.detailTextLabel Outside Of TableView Protocols

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tableview

i have a tableView with 3 cells.

i want to change .detailTextLabel of that cells after tableView loaded.

how i can do that?

i triad this:

> UITableViewCell *firstCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];
>
> firstCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"ABC";
>
> [tableView reloadData];

but this is not doing nothing. what the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
UITableViewCell *firstCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];
```

use

```
UITableViewCell *firstCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UITableViewCell *firstCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

firstCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"ABC";
```

no need to call reloadData.

Comment: Have you commented [tableView reloadData]; and where you are changing detailTextLabel, because if you are changing before your tableview delegate methods are called, then cellForRowAtIndexPath will override your value.

Comment: i call it after my tableView delegate methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

when you say

[tableView reloadData];

that time your : -

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

method will be called for three times as you have 3 cell in your row and this will again override your firstCell.detailTextLabel.text with the original text that you must be providing through your array...

so if you are using array.. then you need to change the object in that array for the required index.

just implement this:

[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Change"];

[tableViewCategory reloadData];

hope so this will work for you...